# Jenkins build using variable ${GIT_BRANCH} as sonarqube parameter without "origin/"

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube

Large team with separate git branches per team and sonar as a code quality checker.

The scm tool is set up to pick up every branch that corresponds to this name: `'feature-branch-*'` which works perfectly, for the maven build. 
I wanted to set up sonarqube so it would use a different branch for every actual git branch, but sonarqube does not allow wildcards.
It does however allow variables so I tried `${GIT_BRANCH}`, but this variable holds: `'origin/feature-branch-214'`, which sonarqube does not recognise as a valid branch name. Sonarqube expects `'feature-branch-214'`

So I need something to put there (in sonarqube branch) that does **a substring of the `${GIT_BRANCH}` to exclude the `'origin/'` part.**

Answer (score 6):

You could create a new variable and assign the value:

```
`echo ${GIT_BRANCH} | cut -d'/' -f 2-`
```

Afterwards, you will be able to use the new variable in the Jenkins Git Branch SonarQube parameter, by following the below steps.

**Steps**

In build section add an `Execute Shell` step with `command`:

```
echo NEW_VAR=`echo ${GIT_BRANCH} | cut -d'/' -f 2-` > newfile
```

Then add an `Inject an environment variable` step with `Properties File Path`:

```
newfile
```

In SonarQube configuration leave the `branch` field `empty` and add the following in the `Additional properties field`:

```
-Dsonar.branch=${NEW_VAR}
```

*The above solution is not very clean but I've verified that it works*

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer, could you please provide some explanation for this command, cause it does not seem to do what I want.

Comment: You're right. Now it should work. The command splits the GIT_BRANCH variable using / as a delimiter and then it selects the second field.

Comment: Beware of this kind of use of `cut`.  For instance: `echo origin/bran/ch | cut -d/ -f 2` outputs `bran`, not `bran/ch`.  I am not sure how portable this is but `cut -d -f 2-` makes it output `bran/ch` as desired.

Comment: I got the command to work, and stored it in the variable, but it seems to be available only in the shell script build step: I added a variable (parameterized it, because without that the variable does not live outside the pre build step) to the build, gave it a default value, echoed it, stored the calculated value in it, echoed it to ensure the correct value is stored in the variable. Till here this works, further the variable is not changed in the actual sonar post build step..

Comment: @torek you're right. thanks :) I've updated the answer with your tip.

Comment: To make sure this also works with branch names with more slashes, such as `origin/feature/branchname` I used: 
    `echo NEW_VAR=\`echo ${GIT_BRANCH} | sed 's/\//-/g'\` > newfile`

Answer (score 6):

Or you could:

```
echo NEW_VAR=${GIT_BRANCH#*/} > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ${GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH}, this without "origin/"

GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH – the name of the local Git branch when the “checkout to specific local branch” Jenkins Git plugin option is selected
If given, checkout the revision to build as HEAD on this branch.

If selected, and its value is an empty string or "**", then the branch name is computed from the remote branch without the origin. In that case, a remote branch origin/master will be checked out to a local branch named master, and a remote branch origin/develop/new-feature will be checked out to a local branch named develop/newfeature.

Please note that this has not been tested with submodules.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Ruk.png)

Comment: That answer should be accepted. I was facing the exactly same issue and didn't understand why the GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH env var from "${YOUR_JENKINS_HOST}/env-vars.html" doesn't work. Adding this additional checkout behavior made it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
git show-ref | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD) | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | sed -e 's/.*remotes.origin.//'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the Jenkins environmental variable GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH instead of GIT_BRANCH. You can see the full list of Jenkins environmental variables at http://[jenkins-url]/env-vars.html