# How can I strip "origin" from ${GIT_BRANCH} in jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

How can you strip "`origin`" from the `${GIT_BRANCH}` in your jenkins job.

For example my `${GIT_BRANCH}` has `origin/develop`: how would I strip origin from `${GIT_BRANCH}` and get just `develop`?

I am trying to pass this value to another jenkins job.

Comment: You should be able to use `${GIT_BRANCH##origin}` or similar. See also: the Bash Reference Manual [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 5):

In case you are looking for a solution which **works in regular pipeline jobs and multibranch pipeline jobs** using a Jenkinsfile and want to set a stable environment variable in the "environment" section:

```
BRANCH_NAME = "${GIT_BRANCH.replaceFirst(/^.*\//, '')}"
```

Background info: For me, these solutions did *not* work:

- ${BRANCH_NAME}: Set in multibranch pipeline, not in regular pipline.
- ${GIT_BRANCH}: Set to local branch name in multibranch pipeline, but with prefix "origin/" in regular pipeline
- ${BRANCH}: Set in regular pipeline only
- ${GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH}: Found it in the Git plugin documentation, but not set, at least not in multibranch pipeline
- ${GIT_BRANCH,fullName=false}: Syntax error, cannot be parsed, found references to that on SO but no documentation.

Comment: To make "GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH" work, you may try adding "Checkout to specific/matching local branch" as additional behavior in the repository config, as it was stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65335872/9732314 . This solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

From [JENKINS-25465](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25465)

> you must set fullName to false to strip origin.

```
${GIT_BRANCH,fullName=false}
```

[jmogera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891906/jmogera) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421257/how-can-i-strip-origin-from-git-branch-in-jenkins/39421341#comment84132128_39421341):

> seemed to work for me. This is what I have:
>
> ```
> ${GIT_BRANCH,fullName=false}-${BUILD_NUMBER}
> ```

Comment: I did try that, as a part of passing predefined parameters to another jenkins job.                                                     BuildBranch=${GIT_BRANCH,fullName=false}
BuildDisplayName=#${VenueBuildNumber}_${GIT_BRANCH,fullName=false} But that doesnt seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Comment: This produces origin/develop for me (Used in an execute shell post step).

Comment: seemed to work for me. This is what I have: ${GIT_BRANCH,fullName=false}-${BUILD_NUMBER}

Comment: i wonder where this works and where the doc is which is mentioned in Jenkins-25465. For me it leads to syntax error when used in the "environment" section of a Jenkinsfile in a multibranch pipeline job.

Comment: @MoritzBoth 4 years later, I don't know: maybe the plugin has evolved and made this syntax obsolete?

Comment: @VonC of course. just posted my findings here after searching for a solution for some hours... oh well. have a nice day and thanks for posting your original solution :)